# Is this ring merchandise with a red seal and gold "忍" emblem exist in Naruto?

Tags: naruto, merchandise, cosplay

This is a ring with a red seal and gold "忍" emblem.

[image: a ring with a red seal and gold "忍" emblem]

I don't know whether this type of ring is in *Naruto*.

Who wears it? Is it a knockoff?

Comment: Can you include additional information? Like where did you buy it or what is the product description from the store you bought it from?

Comment: It looks like one of Akatsuki rings, but the Japanese character there in your photo is different from all of the Akatsuki rings. It might be a knock off.

Comment: The Japanese character is [忍](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%BF%8D) which is *shinobu* (sneak) and part of *nin*ja. However, it'd be better if you could [edit] and give an additional context of why you believe it's from *Naruto*.

Comment: It looks like an akatsuki ring but with the allied shinobi forces emblem on it instead, assuming it's indeed from Naruto. That said, I can't recall anywhere in the anime where someone was wearing such an accessory.

Comment: Judging by the metal working, it is a hand crafted ring, made by somebody whom is not very skilled in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a ring made in the style of the [Akatsuki rings](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Akatsuki#Rings). However such designs are merely inspired and have little to no bearing to the Naruto franchise itself.

I will not post links to any online vendors, but you will find many like it from various vendors if you do a cursory Google search for something like "shinobi symbol ring." If you add Naruto to the query you might get more franchise relevant.